aesthetic colour was dropped during statistical transformation
I used a Likert scale for all three variables: IV, DV, and Moderating Variable. I used 4 or 5-item scales, which I aggregated successfully. I also coded the main effect for the IV and DV, however, I have problems plotting a graph for the moderation effect. Can anyone help me?
R Code:
 mod_effect_1 <- process (data = test_responses, y = "Overall_AttitudeAggregated", 
     x = "Overall_EnvironmentalA", w ="Overall_Comp", model = 1)
 
 mod_effect_1_plot <- ggplot(test_responses, aes(x = Overall_Comp, 
                                            y = Overall_AttitudeAggregated, 
                                            color = Overall_EnvironmentalA))+
geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x, fullrange = TRUE, fill = "gray80") +
labs(x = "Perceived Compatibility",
   y = "Attitude towards Sustainable Luxury Fashion") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) +
scale_color_gradient(low = "red", high = "blue", name = "Overall Environmental A") +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))

Warning message:
The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: colour.
ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in the data.
ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a factor? 


It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Explicitly list all non-base R packages you are using.

@MrFlick Please see the non-base R packages below:
library(readxl)
library(psych)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(emmeans)
library(plotrix)
source("process.R")
Please see here for the code:
dataset <- read_excel("Responses from qualtrics.xlsx")
#CREATING OVERALL SCALE SCORES (Aggregation)
#IV 1 (I did the same for DV1, creating the new column dataset$DV_1 and the moderator, creating new column dataset$ModV_1)
dataset$IV_1 <- rowMeans(dataset[,c("IV E_1", "IV E_2", "IV E_3", "IV E_4", "IV E_5")], na.rm=TRUE), next I computed the main effect (IV1 and DV1).

@MrFlick
Next, I tried to compute the moderation effect and create a plot (this is were I experienced difficulties)
mod_effect_1 <- process(data = dataset, y = "DV_1_Aggregated",
x = "IV_1_Aggregated", w ="ModV_1_Aggregated", model = 1)

@MrFlick Hope this is clear for you!
mod_effect_1_plot <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = ModV_1_Aggregated,
y = DV_1_Aggregated,
color = IV_1_Aggregated))+
geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x, fullrange = TRUE, fill = "gray80") +
labs(x = "Mod Label", y = "DV Label") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) +
scale_color_gradient(low = "red", high = "blue", name = "Overall Environmental A") + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))
